# What IOC containers work with Windows Azure

Tags: inversion-of-control, azure

I am getting to grips with Windows Azure. I usually use NInject as my IoC container in web apps. However, when trying to use it within an Azure web role I get a security exception (something to do with reflection permission).

Has anyone used other IoC with Azure and had succcess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just have been prototyping with Azure services today (not Web role, though). 
Autofac IoC Container for .NET has worked in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

From Ninject google group: http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/8d5a0aff853c6b4f/20209877f8db179a?show_docid=20209877f8db179a

If you set the kernel option UseReflectionBasedInjection, Ninject will work 
in Azure (as well as other partial trust environments):

```
var options = new KernelOptions
{ 
    UseReflectionBasedInjection = true
}; 
var kernel = new StandardKernel(options, new ModuleA(), new ModuleB(), ...);
```

Comment: I've tried to use NInject before, but it did lack fast performance support for complex container hierarchies (and transient instances) and deterministic disposal. Windsor had a couple of issues in these areas, as well.

Comment: The deterministic disposal story for windsor has improved recently due to the introduction of component burden.